# Case_when statements in pipe operator on a vector

Tags: r, vector, dplyr, pipe

I am trying to understand how to better use `if else` or `case_when` in a pipeline when manipulating a vector. After scraping an element of a website I am left with this vector:

```
[1] "66"        "121"       "112 - 150" "211"       "197"       "25"        "72"       
[8] "59"        "100"       "69 - 194" 

c("66", "121", "112 - 150", "211", "197", "25", "72", "59", "100", 
"69 - 194")

library(tidyverse)
library(stringr) (1.5.0)
```

I want to manipulate them in a vector before I put them in a dataframe/tibble.
Such that if there are two numbers in a string (ex. 112 - 150), replace it with the mean of the two. I have tried the following:

```
vector %>%
  case_when(
    str_detect(., "-") ~ . %>%
      str_split_1(" - ") %>%
      as.numeric() %>%
      mean(),
    T ~ .
  )
```

Which does not work. Individually, it works:

```
"112 - 150" %>% 
  str_split_1(" - ") %>% 
  as.numeric() %>% 
  mean()

[1] 131
```

Then I thought perhaps `case_when()` does not work with a vector. But it clearly does:

```
case_when(
  vector == "66" ~ "SIXSIX", 
  TRUE ~ "NOT 66"
)

 [1] "SIXSIX" "NOT 66" "NOT 66" "NOT 66" "NOT 66" "NOT 66" "NOT 66" "NOT 66"
 [9] "NOT 66" "NOT 66"
```

I would prefer a suggestion without the conventional if statement as such:

```
vector %>% 
  {if (cond) ** else **}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When written with a pipe, `vector %>% case_when(...)` evaluates as `case_when(vector, ...)`, but since even the first argument of `case_when` must be a two-sided formula, it returns an error. Hence the message:

> Error in `case_when()`: ! Case 1 (`.`) must be a two-sided formula,
> not a   character vector.

In this case, you don't need `case_when`, since you can apply `mean` even to single elements:

```r
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

vector %>% 
  str_split(' - ') %>% 
  map_dbl(~ mean(as.numeric(.x)))
#[1]  66.0 121.0 131.0 211.0 197.0  25.0  72.0  59.0 100.0 131.5
```

With `case_when`, this still works:

```r
case_when( 
  str_detect(vector, "-") ~ vector %>% 
    str_split(' - ') %>% 
    map_dbl(~ mean(as.numeric(.x))),
  T ~ as.numeric(vector)
)
```

Comment: Bravo  @Maël. Very good explanation and perfect solution!

Comment: Right on the money @Maël, thanks for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

An option is to use `read.table` to read the data in to a two column data.frame and use `rowMeans` in `base R`

```
rowMeans(read.table(text = vector, header = FALSE, sep = '-', 
  fill = TRUE), na.rm = TRUE)
```

-output

```
 [1]  66.0 121.0 131.0 211.0 197.0  25.0  72.0  59.0 100.0 131.5
```

---

Or in a pipe

```
vector|> 
  read.table(text = _, header = FALSE, sep = '-', fill = TRUE) |> 
   rowMeans(na.rm = TRUE)
 [1]  66.0 121.0 131.0 211.0 197.0  25.0  72.0  59.0 100.0 131.5
```