# ! Case 1 (`.`) must be a two-sided formula, not a double vector

Tags: r, tidyverse, case, purrr

My code is as below:

```
data = data.frame(x1 = c(1,1,1,1)
                 ,x2 = c(0,1,0,1)
                 ,x3 = c(1,1,0,1),x4 = c(1,1,0,0)) %>% rowSums

data%>%
        case_when(. == 0 ~ 0,
                  . %in% c(1,2)~ 1,
                  . %in% c(3:5)~ 2)
```

The sample data is as below:

| x1 | x2 | x3 | x4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |

where `x1,x2,x3,x4` are in one data frame and they are binary variables.
Then, the rowsums of `x1,x2,x3,x4` are calculated.

The result is as below:

| rowsums |
| --- |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 1 |
| 3 |

I would like to use case_when to do classification, however, when I run the above code, the error:
`! Case 1 (`.`) must be a two-sided formula, not a double vector.` also appears and I cannot solve it by using different method...

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74914635/case-when-statements-in-pipe-operator-on-a-vector/74914748#74914748

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pipe inserts the left-hand expression as the first argument into the right-hand side call.

That is, your call is equivalent to:

```
case_when(data,
          data == 0 ~ 0,
          data %in% c(1,2) ~ 1,
          data %in% c(3:5) ~ 2)
```

To prevent this, surround the right-hand side with `{…}`:

```
data %>% {
  case_when(. == 0 ~ 0,
            . %in% c(1,2) ~ 1,
            . %in% c(3:5) ~ 2)
}
```

[The documentation](https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/reference/pipe.html#using-the-dot-for-secondary-purposes) gives the following description:

> For example, `iris %>% subset(1:nrow(.) %% 2 == 0)` is equivalent to `iris %>% subset(., 1:nrow(.) %% 2 == 0)` but slightly more compact. It is possible to overrule this behavior by enclosing the `rhs` in braces. For example, `1:10 %>% {c(min(.), max(.))}` is equivalent to `c(min(1:10), max(1:10))`.

Comment: You mean pipe only insert `data` to case 1?